# The Area of shaded region in a circle

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, area, word-problem

I'm having trouble solving this problem.

[image]

I can't solve this.
I don't know where and how to start.

I don't know there is any formula for finding the area for this kind of shape, and if it did, I still can't use it since I all I know is radius of 10cm

Comment: Hint: You can find half of the shaded section if you imagine two radii drawn from the center of one circle to the two vertices of the shaded section, find the area of that sector, and subtract the area of the isosceles triangle made by connecting the ends of the radii.

Comment: In problems like this, it's all about splitting up regions and drawing lines until you've made it into something you _do_ have a formula for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw line segments from the two intersections to each circle's center; these four line segments form a square.  Also draw a line between the two intersection points, dividing the overlap into two wedges and the square into two triangles.

Notice that each wedge is what's left after you take a triangle away from a quarter-circle, and the area of that wedge can be determined accordingly.